# CSS input styling and overflow issues

Tags: html, css

I would love to style my input field very similar to the divs I am building. However, I am unable to solve sizing issues.

Here is an example
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kLwlm

And here is one more (with `overflow:visible` and fixed height)
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Fxjzf

As you can see, it looks very different than the divs, and no matter what I tried, I could not make them look similar. First of all, I would love to make the input in a way that the text will pop put (`overflow: visible`? not working).

Secondly, the `height` should be similar to the divs. Setting the `height` and `line-height` properties does seem to effect the temporary text, but when it's clicked (and started to type) it breaks. (check second example)

Shortly, open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this solution here:**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,700,900,400italic,700italic,900italic);

body {
  margin: 100px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
input{
  border:0;
}

div, input{
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: #ff44ff;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

div {
  padding: 1px 0px 13px 2px;
  color: #999;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a solution. This just replicates the mistake in the input field.
Plus, if you click the input field (in the solution you provided) you will see that the txt is offsetted in the magenta area differently than the divs.

Answer (score 0):

I tried placing the input in `div` and then making the input background to transparent. YOu can play with the spacing to you liking, but it works http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Brcpl

Comment: The forth item at the bottom is the one I changed.

Comment: I edited the last item, not the first. I got rid of the first option, check again.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gump469r/). I removed the line-height and positioned text using padding instead (that fixed the aligning of the input text).I also styled the placeholder. Here is a part of your CSS which I changed (do read the notes in it).

```
div, input{
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: #ff44ff;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;/*use padding to adapt the size*/
}
/*Change placeholder properties*/
#s::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: black;
}
#s:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: black;  
}
#s::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: black;  
}
#s:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: black;  
}
```

PS: I do suggest styling the input-box differently so the visitors of your website notice it is actually a input-box.

Answer (score 0):

What about this one: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lcgAD

**css**

```
div input {
  border: none;  
  font-size: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

div input:hover {

}

div {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #892;
  height: 41px;
}
```

**html**

```
<div>
  <input placeholder="Enter E-Mail ayxml@gmail.com" value="Enter E-Mail ayxml@gmail.com"/>
</div>
```